# Como fazer variável receber valor de argumento de função?

Tags: c, struct

Seguinte: tenho um código de como criar uma estrutura de um ponto em um plano RxR. No caso, eu gostaria de acessar o valor "x" de um ponto. Seguem os códigos:

Arquivo ponto.h:

```
 //Arquivo Ponto.h
 typedef struct ponto Ponto;

 //Cria um novo ponto
 Ponto* pto_cria(float x, float y);

 //Libera um ponto
 void pto_libera(Ponto* p);

 //Acessa os valores "x" e "y" de um ponto
 int pto_acessa(Ponto* p, float* x, float* y);

 //Atribui os valores "x" e "y" a um ponto
 int pto_atribui(Ponto* p, float x, float y);

 //Calcula a distância entre dois pontos
 float pto_distancia(Ponto* p1, Ponto* p2);
```

Arquivo ponto.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Ponto.h" //inclui os Protótipos

//Definição do tipo de dados
  struct ponto{
    float x;
    float y;
  };

//Aloca e retorna um ponto com coordenadas "x" e "y"
Ponto* pto_cria(float x, float y){
       Ponto* p = (Ponto*) malloc(sizeof(Ponto));
       if(p != NULL){
           p->x = x;
           p->y = y;
       }
       return p;
 }

 //Libera a memória alocada para um ponto
 void pto_libera(Ponto* p){
         free(p);
 }

 //Recupera, por referência, o valor de um ponto
 int pto_acessa(Ponto* p, float* x, float* y){
      if(p == NULL)
           return 0;
      *x = p->x;
      *y = p->y;
      return 1;
 }

 //Atribui a um ponto as coordenadas "x" e "y"
 int pto_atribui(Ponto* p, float x, float y){
      if(p == NULL)
         return 0;
      p->x = x;
      p->y = y;
      return 1;
 }

//Calcula a distância entre dois pontos
float pto_distancia(Ponto* p1, Ponto* p2){
      if(p1 == NULL || p2 == NULL)
           return -1;
      float dx = p1->x - p2->x;
      float dy = p1->y - p2->y;
      return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
 }
```

Arquivo main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Ponto.h"

int main(){
   float d;
   Ponto *p,*q;

   p = pto_cria(10,21);
   q = pto_cria(7,25);

   //Aqui, quero que a variável x1 receba o valor "x" de p
   float x1 = p->x;


   d = pto_distancia(p,q);


   printf("Ponto 1: %f\n", x1);
   printf("Distancia entre pontos: %f\n", d);

   pto_libera(q);
   pto_libera(p);

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Só que quando faço isso, recebo a mensagem: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type.

Qual seria a forma correta de fazer isso? Seria utilizando a função pto_associa?

Fonte do código: https://programacaodescomplicada.wordpress.com/complementar/

Comment: Aonde a mensagem de erro acontece?

Comment: Na linha float x1 = p->x;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você tenta acessar o membro `x` do struct `p` o compilador precisa saber como esse struct parece (por exemplo, para verificar se realmente existe algum membro `x` dentro dele). Como você não colocou a definição do tipo `struct ponto` em qualquer lugar onde o compilador possa vê-lo ao compilar `main.c`, você recebe um erro. O compilador não sabe o que um `struct ponto` contém.

Se você colocar a definição de `struct ponto` em `ponto.h`,

```
typedef struct ponto{
   float x;
   float y;
}Ponto;
```

o compilador consegue ver como esse tipo é estruturado e os membros do struct podem ser usados.

Insira a definição completa do tipo `struct ponto` em `ponto.h`, é aí que deveria estar.

Comment: Pois é. Acabei colocando a estrutura no Ponto.c achando que seria lá. Quando coloquei no Ponto.h, deu certo. Obrigado!